# Difficulty with dictionary order function

Tags: python

Write a function named "indexed_kvs" that doesn't take any parameters and returns a new key-value store containing the integers from 0 to 36 as values each stored at a key which is a string containing the digits of the integer. For example the key-value "0":0 will be in your returned key-value store (include both 0 and 36 in your list). (My code below)

```
def indexed_kvs():
    d = dict()
    for x in range(37):
        d[x] = x
        return d
```

I keep on getting the first key and value; how do I get all the keys and values?

Comment: Your return shouldnt be in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You return from inside the loop which is a common mistake that can be avoided altogether by using a [`dict` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), at least in this simple case:

```
def indexed_kvs():
    return {str(x): x for x in range(37)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Loocid comment, the return statement shouldn't be inside the for loop, so the correct code would be:

```
def indexed_kvs():
    d = dict()
    for x in range(37):
        d[str(x)] = x
    return d
```

Comment: Like this, the code wouldn't give any error. But, as said in the question "stored at a key which is a string" you're right, edit coming

Answer (score 0):

You have your "return d", inside you loop. So, what happens is that -

1) The function begins

2) The `for` loop executes once:

a) adds `0` to the dictionary at key `0`,

b) encounters `return d`, them thinks- 'Okay! I got a return statement. I gotta exit! '

c) And Boom! Your function is done with

So, just move your `return d` out of you for loop. So, the exiting of the function will take place when, the loop is over.

So your new code should be:

```
def indexed_kvs():
    d = dict()
    for x in range(37):
        d[str(x)] = x
    return d
```